# Neo4j appears to have deadlock when testing with org.neo4j.ogm.testutil.TestServer

Tags: java, neo4j, spring-data-neo4j-4

We use for org.neo4j.ogm.testutil.TestServer for integration testing our API. During test execution, all tests freeze (like deadlock), in the same place every time. Could this be something we're doing wrong with neo4j?

Java version - 1.8.74. neo4j version - 3.0.3

Last logs:

```
18:10:45.808 [qtp234760309-36] INFO  o.n.o.d.http.request.HttpRequest - Thread 36: request {"statements":[{"statement":"MATCH (n:`EmailAddressPasswordAccount`) WHERE n.`email` = { `email` } WITH n MATCH p=(n)-[*0..1]-(m) RETURN p, ID(n)","parameters":{"email":"johndeverall@gmail.com"},"resultDataContents":["graph","row"],"includeStats":false}]}
18:10:45.811 [qtp234760309-36] INFO  o.n.o.d.http.request.HttpRequest - Thread 36: POST http://localhost:7474/db/data/transaction/commit HTTP/1.1
18:10:46.170 [qtp234760309-36] INFO  o.n.o.d.http.request.HttpRequest - Thread 36: POST http://localhost:7474/db/data/transaction HTTP/1.1
18:10:46.205 [qtp234760309-36] INFO  o.n.o.d.http.request.HttpRequest - Thread 36: request {"statements":[{"statement":"UNWIND {rows} as row CREATE (n:`EmailAddressPasswordAccount`:`Account`) SET n=row.props RETURN row.nodeRef as nodeRef, ID(n) as nodeId","parameters":{"rows":[{"nodeRef":-132953529,"props":{"password":"testtest","sceneId":"tPfD4WyJSCqi1Wt-ruWJ4A","emailConfirmationCode":"uvduK8F4TRKeJbiA745BsQ","email":"johndeverall@gmail.com"}}]},"resultDataContents":["row"],"includeStats":false},{"statement":"UNWIND {rows} as row CREATE (n:`Member`) SET n=row.props RETURN row.nodeRef as nodeRef, ID(n) as nodeId","parameters":{"rows":[{"nodeRef":-485863866,"props":{"firstName":"Some","lastName":"Some","sceneId":"tIEji2KnTR-boD7LyQDamg"}}]},"resultDataContents":["row"],"includeStats":false}]}
18:10:46.209 [qtp234760309-36] INFO  o.n.o.d.http.request.HttpRequest - Thread 36: POST http://localhost:7474/db/data/transaction/4 HTTP/1.1
18:10:48.191 [qtp234760309-36] INFO  o.n.o.d.http.request.HttpRequest - Thread 36: request {"statements":[{"statement":"UNWIND {rows} as row MATCH (startNode) WHERE ID(startNode) = row.startNodeId MATCH (endNode) WHERE ID(endNode) = row.endNodeId MERGE (startNode)-[rel:`SIGN_IN_MECHANISM`]->(endNode) RETURN row.relRef as relRefId, ID(rel) as relId","parameters":{"rows":[{"startNodeId":1,"relRef":-96372006,"endNodeId":0}]},"resultDataContents":["row"],"includeStats":false}]}
18:10:48.194 [qtp234760309-36] INFO  o.n.o.d.http.request.HttpRequest - Thread 36: POST http://localhost:7474/db/data/transaction/4 HTTP/1.1
18:10:48.801 [qtp234760309-36] INFO  o.n.o.d.http.request.HttpRequest - Thread 36: POST http://localhost:7474/db/data/transaction/4/commit HTTP/1.1
18:10:49.434 [qtp234760309-36] INFO  o.n.o.d.http.request.HttpRequest - Thread 36: request {"statements":[{"statement":"UNWIND {rows} as row MATCH (n) WHERE ID(n)=row.nodeId SET n:`Member` SET n += row.props","parameters":{"rows":[{"nodeId":1,"props":{"loadAllMembersAssociatedWithSocialServiceProvider":null,"firstName":"Some","lastName":"Some","mergeConfirmationCode":null,"phoneNumber":"555-5555","sceneId":"tIEji2KnTR-boD7LyQDamg","mergeRequesterSceneId":null}}]},"resultDataContents":["row"],"includeStats":false}]}
18:10:49.437 [qtp234760309-36] INFO  o.n.o.d.http.request.HttpRequest - Thread 36: POST http://localhost:7474/db/data/transaction/commit HTTP/1.1
```

Comment: Use `jstack` to do a thread dump and find out where the server is blocking, that would be a starting point.